# Do heal spells (Like Janna's Ult) proc Spell Vamp?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does spell Vamp from Will of the Ancients trigger from heals like Janna's Monsoon, Soraka's Wish, or even Nidalee's Primal surge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**

Spell vamp triggers on the DAMAGE dealed by spells.

None of the skills below deal any kind of damage, so spell vamp does not apply at any moment.

> Spell vamp applies to everything that isn't classified as an
>   auto-attack. This is most abilities, but also includes items (e.g. 
>   Hextech Gunblade) and summoner spells (e.g.  Smite).

- **[Monsoon](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Janna_the_Storm%27s_Fury)**

> (Active): Janna knocks surrounding enemies back and channels healing
>   winds, restoring health to nearby allies each half second, for 4
>   seconds.

- **[Wish](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Soraka_the_Starchild)**

> (Active): Soraka fills her allies with hope, instantly restoring
>   health to all allied champions regardless of where they are.

- **[Primal Surge](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nidalee_the_Bestial_Huntress)**

> (Active): Nidalee heals an ally champion and grants them bonus attack speed for 7 seconds.

- **[Spell vamp](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spell_vamp)**

> Spell vamp is a magic stat. The spell vamp works as a counterpart of
>   life steal, but instead of regenerating health based on autoattacks,
>   the regeneration is based on damage done by champion abilities.

Answer (score 5):

No, they do not. Spell Vamp works specifically with "Damage." It does, however, work with Smite.